# Python dataframe turn click path row to column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python Pandas dataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 'm':['email', 'organic', 'cpc', 'cpc', 'direct']})
print df
   id        m
0   1    email
1   1  organic
2   1      cpc
3   2      cpc
4   2   direct
```

After transformation, I want to get

```
df_transformed = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2], 'path' :['p1-p3-p2', 'p2-p1']})
print df_transformed
   id      path
0   1  p1-p3-p2
1   2     p2-p1
```

Please note that the page path length for each id may be different.

How could I get this? thanks.

Comment: Where the p1,p2,p3 come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, what do you do exactly.

So, I try more combination:

### 1.input with "p"

from revision of your answer, I get:
 `d = {'id':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 'path':['p1', 'p3', 'p2', 'p2', 'p1']}`

then code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'id':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 'path':['p1', 'p3', 'p2', 'p2', 'p1']}
o = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2], 'path' :['p1-p3-p2', 'p2-p1']})

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print df
print o

df = df.groupby('id').agg({'path': lambda x: '-'.join(x)})
print df
```

```
        path
id
1   p1-p3-p2
2      p2-p1
```

### 2.output with "m words"

it means:

```
o = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2], 'm' :['email-organic-cpc', 'cpc-direct']})
```

then code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'id':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 'm':['email', 'organic', 'cpc', 'cpc', 'direct']}
o = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2], 'm' :['email-organic-cpc', 'cpc-direct']})

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print df
print o

df = df.groupby('id').agg({'m': lambda x: '-'.join(x)})
print df
```

```
                    m
id
1   email-organic-cpc
2          cpc-direct
```

### 3. remapping - from "m" to "p"

(I have to change last item `direct` to `email`, because remapping will be wrong)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'id':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 'm':['email', 'organic', 'cpc', 'cpc', 'email']}
o = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2], 'path' :['p1-p3-p2', 'p2-p1']})

dictionary = {'email': 'p1', 'cpc': 'p2', 'organic': 'p3'}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print df
df = df.replace({'m': dictionary})
df = df.rename(columns = { 'm':'path'})

print df
print o

df = df.groupby('id').agg({'path': lambda x: '-'.join(x)})
print df
```

```
        path
id
1   p1-p3-p2
2      p2-p1
```